# Seleccionar columnas a partir de los registros de otra tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta que aún no he podido solucionar.

Resulta que quiero seleccionar los campos de una tabla. El problema esta que estos campos no son fijos sino que estan almacenados en otra tabla 'Tabla1'

```
SELECT Campos FROM Tabla1

Campos
------
Col1
Col2
Col3
```

A partir de estos registros quiero formar una cadena que me permita seleccionar los campos obtenidos de la otra tabla.

De esta manera:

```
SELECT Col, Col2, Col3 FROM Cuentas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es armar una sentencia dinámicamente para obtener los capos que deseas. Con las sentencias dinámicas hay que tener cuidado en dos cosas, por un lado hay que tener en cuenta que perdemos la posibilidad que el motor optimice la consulta como suele suceder con consultas normales, y por otro lado hay que tener cuidado ya que son sentencias dónde fácilmente se podría inyectar código.

Como prueba de concepto:

```
-- Tabla de campos
DECLARE @TablaCampos TABLE (
    Campo   VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @TablaCampos (Campo)
SELECT  'id'    UNION
SELECT  'name'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Armo el select dinámico con los campos prefijados
SELECT  @SQL = 'SELECT  '
SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + Campo + ','
    FROM @TablaCampos

SELECT  @SQL = left(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 1) + ' FROM sysobjects'

-- Ejecuto la sentencia dinámica
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, y tendré en cuenta tus consejos. Saludos